# Prevent parent to trigger transition if a child is clicked

Tags: javascript, css

I have a `.card` that changes its scale when `:active`. But I don't want this rule to run if a `button` within this `.card` is clicked.

To better illustrate the situation, this is my current code:

`.html`:

```html
<div class="card">
  <h1>Card</h1>
  
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

`.css`:

```css
.card {}

.card:active {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

button {
  /** ? **/
}
```

To better illustrate the situation, here's a demo of what's going on: https://codepen.io/chiefGui/pen/BaJoVvg

I lack ideas on how to overcome this situation via HTML/CSS only - so, what would you do?

---

**Note: The solution I'm looking for is a way to solve the problem without JavaScript interference (if possible at all).**

Comment: You can add `pointer-events: none;` to the `.card`

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx wouldn't that make any child element unclickable?

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx I cannot, otherwise, it won't ever trigger the transform transition. I do want the transform, but not when the `button` is clicked.

Comment: You need to prevent the propagation of the event, Not possible using CSS. One option is changing the structure of the markup: making the `button` and the `.card`  elements siblings and using absolute positioning for positioning the button. This way `.card `is not the parent and does not inherit the event from the button.

Comment: @CornelRaiu Well, it does... sort of. Those answers are from 2015 - 7 years from now. A lot has changed. I'd like to know what modern approaches would be.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge if you want to avoid JS, the `:focus-within` is perfectly fine for using in 2022. The difference between those answers and now is that Edge now fully supports it https://caniuse.com/?search=focus-within

Comment: This is a codepen from that question ( the only 2018 answer in there ) which is exactly what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/s0at4w4b/42/ . This question can certainly be closed as a duplicate